# Bash No such file or directory

Tags: bash

trying to write a bash where the command to be used is specified in a environmental variable, if it is defined. Doing so as follows:

```
if [ -z $MY_DIFF ];
then
    echo Using standard diff $(which diff), change MY_DIFF env variable to use a different one.
    echo $(which diff)
    $diffv=$(which diff)
else
    $diffv=$MY_DIFF
fi

$diffv c.xml c2.xml
```

But I'm getting:

```
./bash.sh: line 10: =/opt/gnu/bin/diff: No such file or directory
./bash.sh: line 13: c.xml: command not found
```

I'm sure the file exists and I do have permission to execute. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Could you include line numbers to show more clearly where the error is pointing?

Comment: You have a '=' in front of the diff path.

Comment: Don't use $ on the left side of assignments (this is literal output from [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) when run on your script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra `$` before `diffv` assignment. Use:

```
diffv=$(which diff)
```

And:

```
diffv=$MY_DIFF
```

With `$` you get:

```
<diffv value, empty>=<MY_DIFF value, or which diff>
=/opt/gnu/bin/diff
```